# How to get api level information from classes.dex

Tags: android

My application is supposed to examine an android application and decides whether it is a malware or not.Examination part includes extracting information from manifest.xml file and classes.dex file. The problem is I dont know how to get api level information from dex code. I need to get all classes names, used variables, api calls etc. Is there any built in support in android for getting this information from classes.dex file ? Code example would be really appreciated. Thanks